# how to detect a web browser closing and log it

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I want to detect and close a browser window. But before closing the browser page I need to update a SQL entry in an InUse table. There are a couple of unique situations added to this. When the EditPage.aspx opens for a (recordID record in a MstrTbl)  I place an entry in the InUse table. I am tracking recno (autogenerated), userid, sessionid, recordID (MstrTbl), status, rectype, rwindicator, createdatetime, updatedatetime. I am using Session("gUserID") [all Session("variables")] when updating InUse table. The variables are fairly straight forward. But, there can be multiple users opening the same recordID, however, only 1st user in can edit. (Thus, rwindicator, Read/Write Indicator). In days of yore, you could control a vb6 app opening only once, but now in web world, a user can open multiple browsers (and records), and in this case need to be able to do so.

Okay, so if there is an InUse entry for this user, and this recordID, redirect the 2nd attempt to an error page (You can only open this record once) error, and back to the Default page for you.

Now a user is finished with a record, and can click Home (Site.Master Menu Item) or can simply click "X" in browser. I DO NOT want a "verify close" message (extra click), but where the InUse table had an [A]ctive status now needs updating time stamp and e[X]pired status. The solution can be java or jquery. I have tried several renditions of many attempts at "catching" the close with window. Using a hidden "btnCloseWindow" in a onbeforeunload functions seems to almost work a larger percent of the time, especially if I set an "alert" msg (which I do not want to do).

Code in the Window.close seems to never be able to update the InUse record. I've also tried timeout intervals. I have tried a dozen variations of different "solutions" (from other programmers attempts) but none seem reliable, if I get 2 or 3 users opening 3 or 4 of the same records, then closing them one at a time. I can create the InUse record. That's easy enough. But when a user closes a recordID, it will not update date/time stamp and status from [A]ctive to e[X]pire. I do not want to insert and delete records. This is an audit trail. But if the same userID opens the same recordID and it still shows [A]ctive, it will not allow the user to (in error) open it again.

The code in the EditPage.aspx.vb runs a Public Shared Sub (RecData.LockRec) in code behind, but then needs to run (RecData.CloseRec) when the "X" or "Home" Menu item is clicked.

In advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is nearly impossible to send a message to the server on window close in modern browsers. Also what happens in the state of power loss or critical error and the browser crashes. You would not get a ping either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [window.onclose](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclose) event but note you have a very small amount of time so your backend has to accept the posted event quickly. The browser will only wait for a short amount of time. So if you are doing anything complicated, accept the POST/GET from the client and then close the connection and *then* process the POST/GET.